# set the top position of a section in parallax

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

I have used the above script to show smooth parallax scrolling. It works properly and the section stops at the start of screen. I want the particular section to stop some pixels below the screen. Can anyone please help.

Comment: `'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - somepixels`

Comment: There is a small problem.In mozilla it stops at the given position and then again go back to the top of the screen